# How to convert this piece of elixir code to Erlang?

Tags: erlang, elixir

There is a piece of code in elixir that checks if node is alive or not and makes some operations on the basis of that. How to implement the same functionality in erlang?

```
def make_distributed([head | tail],l) do
        unless Node.alive?() do
            try do
                {ip_tuple,_,_} = head
                current_ip = to_string(:inet_parse.ntoa(ip_tuple))
                if current_ip === "127.0.0.1" do
                    if l > 1 do
                        make_distributed(tail,l-1)
                    else 
                        IO.puts "Could not make current node distributed."
                    end
                else
                    server_node_name = String.to_atom("client@" <> current_ip)
                    Node.start(server_node_name)
                    Node.set_cookie(server_node_name,:monster)
                    Node.connect(String.to_atom("server@" <> current_ip))
                end
            rescue
                _ -> if l > 1, do: make_distributed(tail,l-1), else: IO.puts "Could not make current node distributed."
            end
        end
    end
```

if...else works differently in erlang, and I tried changing it to that format but some of the functonalities that are there in elixir code are hard to show in erlang.

Answer (score 1):

First, a direct translation…

```erlang
make_distributed([Head | Tail], L) ->
  case node:is_alive() of
    false ->
      false; % Not sure what unless returns if the condition is false
    true ->
      try
        {IPTuple, _, _} = Head,
        CurrentIP = iolist_to_binary(inet_parse:ntoa(IPTuple)),
        case CurrentIP of
          <<"127.0.0.1">> ->
            case L of
              L when L > 1 ->
                make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
              _ ->
                io:format("Could not make current node distributed.")
            end;
          _ ->
            ServerNodeName = binary_to_atom(<<"client@", CurrentIP/binary>>),
            net_kernel:start([ServerNodeName, longnames, 15000]),
            erlang:set_cookie(ServerNodeName, monster),
            net_kernel:connect_node(binary_to_atom(<<"server@", CurrentIP/binary>>))
        end
      catch
        _:_ ->
          case L of
            L when L > 1 ->
              make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
            _ ->
              io:format("Could not make current node distributed.")
          end
      end
  end.
```

But that's some very ugly code. Let's use pattern-matching more effectively…

```erlang
make_distributed([{IPTuple, _, _} | Tail], L) ->
  case node:is_alive() of
    false ->
      false; % Not sure what unless returns if the condition is false
    true ->
      try
        case iolist_to_binary(inet_parse:ntoa(IPTuple)) of
          <<"127.0.0.1">> when L > 1 ->
            make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
          <<"127.0.0.1">> ->
                io:format("Could not make current node distributed.");
          CurrentIP ->
            ServerNodeName = binary_to_atom(<<"client@", CurrentIP/binary>>),
            net_kernel:start([ServerNodeName, longnames, 15000]),
            erlang:set_cookie(ServerNodeName, monster),
            net_kernel:connect_node(binary_to_atom(<<"server@", CurrentIP/binary>>))
        end
      catch
        _:_ when L > 1 ->
          make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
        _:_ ->
          io:format("Could not make current node distributed.")
      end
  end.
```

Still… we don't need to check for node liveness on every recursive step, right?

```erlang
maybe_make_distributed(IPTuples, L) ->
  case node:is_alive() of
    false ->
      false; % Not sure what unless returns if the condition is false
    true ->
      make_distributed(IPTuples, L)
  end.

make_distributed([{IPTuple, _, _} | Tail], L) ->
  try
    case iolist_to_binary(inet_parse:ntoa(IPTuple)) of
      <<"127.0.0.1">> when L > 1 ->
        make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
      <<"127.0.0.1">> ->
        io:format("Could not make current node distributed.");
      CurrentIP ->
        ServerNodeName = binary_to_atom(<<"client@", CurrentIP/binary>>),
        net_kernel:start([ServerNodeName, longnames, 15000]),
        erlang:set_cookie(ServerNodeName, monster),
        net_kernel:connect_node(binary_to_atom(<<"server@", CurrentIP/binary>>))
    end
  catch
    _:_ when L > 1 ->
      make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
    _:_ ->
      io:format("Could not make current node distributed.")
  end.
```

Finally, let's move the `L > 1` check to its own clause like a regular recursive function…

```erlang
maybe_make_distributed(IPTuples, L) ->
  case node:is_alive() of
    false ->
      false; % Not sure what unless returns if the condition is false
    true ->
      make_distributed(IPTuples, L)
  end.

make_distributed(_, 0) ->
  io:format("Could not make current node distributed.");
make_distributed([{IPTuple, _, _} | Tail], L) ->
  try
    case iolist_to_binary(inet_parse:ntoa(IPTuple)) of
      <<"127.0.0.1">> ->
        make_distributed(Tail, L - 1);
      CurrentIP ->
        ServerNodeName = binary_to_atom(<<"client@", CurrentIP/binary>>),
        net_kernel:start([ServerNodeName, longnames, 15000]),
        erlang:set_cookie(ServerNodeName, monster),
        net_kernel:connect_node(binary_to_atom(<<"server@", CurrentIP/binary>>))
    end
  catch
    _:_ ->
      make_distributed(Tail, L - 1)
  end.
```

Now that's kind of the code I would write in Erlang to achieve the same goal as your Elixir code.

Comment: [`if`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/0909940b04a3e22c9ea4fedafa2aac349717011c/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3709-L3726) returns `nil` if not satisfied.

Comment: I guess the same happens for `unless`, right?